# How to add link to formated message in react intl?

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

I am using react intl ^2.4.0 version. I want to add link inside formatted message that gets translated as well. I am using this in combination with 
[react cookie law](https://github.com/Palmabit-IT/react-cookie-law)

i tried to use something like:

```
const link = <a href="google.com">log in</a>;
const msg = `this website uses cookies ${link}`
```

but no luck.

```
const cookieMsg = (
    <FormattedMessage
        id="text"
        defaultMessage="This website uses cookies LINK HERE."
    />
);
```

and in CookieBanner:

```
<IntlProvider locale={lang} messages={messages[lang]}>
    <>
        <CookieBanner
            message={msg}
            ...
        />
    </>
</IntlProvider>
```

Im rendering  directly in app.js. Here it is:

```
<CookieBanner
     message={cookieMsg}
     acceptButtonText={cookieBtn}
     privacyPolicyLinkText={cookiePrivacy}
     policyLink="https://www.google.com"
     showMarketingOption={false}
     showStatisticsOption={false}
     showPreferencesOption={false}
     styles={{
              optionWrapper: {
                  display: "none"
               }
            }}
     />
```

Comment: Why dont you just have two separate elements - one for the message and another for the link? Since the link is at the end anyways.

Comment: how do you mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can pass link as values to FormattedMessage

```
const cookieMsg = (
    <FormattedMessage
        id="text"
        defaultMessage="This website uses cookies {link}."
        values={{
            link: <a href="google.com">
                <FormattedMessage
                    id="link"
                    defaultMessage="log in"
                />
            </a>
        }}
    />
);
```

Comment: It is good but now it just translates link, not message. this part stays the same "this websites uses cookies" I need that translated too. If I use id from file where I store all messages and translations it removes link.

Comment: Never mind I made it. I just added new property to values. Thanks again.